# Query on keyboard navigation - Accessibility

Tags: html, css, angular, accessibility

My requirement is like, on choosing a value from a dropdown of **X-page**, I have to open **Modal-1** and disable the background. If I choose something from Modal-1, it will result in **Modal-2**.
So here I have 2 problems/queries:

1. After opening the Modal-1, instead of getting the focus in the modal, the tab is going in the background elements of X-page.
2. When I closed the Modal-2, I need to get the focus back to Modal-1, but it's not happening, instead the focus is going to X-page. How can I achieve the focus on Modal-1 when Modal-2 is closed?

I have tried autofocus, but its like one-time. when I close the Modal-1 and open again, the tab focus is back to X-page.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

W3.org has a great design pattern page at https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/.  Specifically, there's one for [dialogs](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/dialog-modal/). You have to write a bit of code to keep the *keyboard* focus within the dialog instead of going to the background page **and** you have to write a bit of code to keep the *screen reader* focus within the dialog instead of going to the background.  The [example](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/dialog-modal/examples/dialog/) code shows you one way (*) of doing that.

(*) Note that the [example](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/dialog-modal/examples/dialog/) code has a caution at the very top (you have to expand it to see it) that says:

> The code in this example is not intended for production environments. Before using it for any purpose, read this to understand why.
>
> This is an illustrative example of one way of using ARIA that conforms with the ARIA specification.
>
> - There may be support gaps in some browser and assistive technology combinations, especially for mobile/touch devices. Testing code based on this example with assistive technologies is essential before considering use in production systems.
> - The ARIA and Assistive Technologies Project is developing measurements of assistive technology support for APG examples.
> - Robust accessibility can be further optimized by choosing implementation patterns that maximize use of semantic HTML and heeding the warning that No ARIA is better than Bad ARIA.

Ideally, using the [`<dialog>`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interactive-elements.html#the-dialog-element) element would do all this for you but support for that element isn't fully implemented yet so you have to do it yourself.

Conceptually, it's valid to have a dialog displayed from a dialog. Just follow the same guidelines in the dialog pattern for each dialog. That means when the second dialog is displayed, the user should not be able to <kbd>tab</kbd> to the first dialog in the background nor be able to move their screen reader focus to the first dialog.

And when the second dialog is closed, you need to programmatically move the focus back to the first dialog using `focus()` on an element that's in the first dialog. Specifically, you should put the focus back on the element (`<button>`?) that caused the second dialog to be displayed.